# Why am I getting "Uncaught TypeError" when using Flexslider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I keep getting this message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'flexslider'

I've had the same issue once before. Then the problem was that the page was loading two jQuery libraries. But I don't think that's the case this time.

Do you have any idea? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried to just paste the plugins source code into the console, and then run the `.flexslider()` method, it worked. So it's some kind of a race condition.

Comment: You have two jQuery libraries loading. Look again...in your `<head>` you have jQuery 1.6.2. In your footer (most likely added with `wp_enqueue_script()`) you have `jquery.js`

Answer (score 1):

conflict-ion  may b a problem. You should probably use noConflict()

```
http://api.jquery.com/noconflict/
```

Check the loads using something like Firebug - just to make sure. The error indicates that something is not being loaded.

```
<script src=".../jquery.flexslider-min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery('.featured-slider').flexslider();
});
/script>
```